# How to set div content to vertical?

Tags: html, css

I want all the content to vertical I did:

```
<div class="name left">
      <label for="name">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>

.name
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this not work, is even horizontal, why?

Comment: Giving something a [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) sets its position vertically. So, you've set everything to be vertically in the same position (centered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'vertical', do you want the actual **text** to be rotated so that it goes down the page vertically?

In that case, you're looking for **[`transform: rotate(90deg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)**:

```css
.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="name left">
  <label for="name">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</div>
```

---

If you instead simply want the **[`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)** to sit on top of the **[`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)** (as is stated by the comment), you simply want to give the `label` a **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)** and offset it slightly from the **[`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)**.

**However**, note that this will cause your typing to appear under the text:

```css
.name > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name left">
  <label for="name">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</div>
```

As such, you're probably simply looking for a [**`placeholder` attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) on the `<input>` instead, which will disappear when the user starts typing in the `<input>` (and reappear when they empty it again):

```html
<div class="name left">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome">
</div>
```

This means that the `<label>` is no longer required.

---

In order to have the name **above** the `<input>`, rather than 'on top of' it, you instead simply want to give the `<label>` **[`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**. **[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** take up the full **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** of their parent, so each element is on a new line:

```css
.name > label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="name left">
  <label for="name">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</div>
```

Comment: @IlRagazzoDiCampagna -- Updated my answer to also showcase that :)

Comment: good answer but the result I need is this: https://html5up.net/forty check the footer for name div

Comment: Oh, you want the name **'above'** the `<input>` (not '*on top of*'). That's also easy enough; I've updated my answer again to cover that. However, I'd really recommend reading [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and **clearly** stating **exactly** what you want it the future, providing links like the one you just shared to highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by your explanation, you want the elements inside of `.name` to be in a block order. You're however setting the element `.name` to be in table-cell display whilst its the actual elements inside the `.name` element that should have the display style.

```
.name * {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `<label>` and `<input>` elements display inline by default. To combat this and make the elements display vertically, you can do one of the following:

```
.name > * {
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
.name {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```